# how to change img style width to attribute width in php

Tags: php

How can I go from this

```
<img style="width:200px; height:300px; ...
```

to this

```
<img width="200" height="300" ...
```

with PHP?

Comment: First one is better than second one. Why do you want to go for it?

Comment: I just need to re-size images in an HTML code received by a 3rd party application only if the image width is greater than 320. Width is defined in 'style' attribute in each 'img' tag.

Comment: simple css rule: ` img.someclass { max-with:320px; height: auto!important; }

Answer (score 1):

An easy way can be not to touch to the html...

Find a way to target those images in your css and just adapt the display

```
div.myimages img {
    max-with:320px;
    height: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: i know this is not the most "powerfull" and elegant solution, but it's dam simple!! I don't see why it deserves a -1 !!
The question itself is far from elegant!

Tristup's solution is far better then mine, I a agree, and regret not to have had the idea... but +1 for all a complex Regex and -1 for simple lick-it stick-it... sad)

Comment: It does not directly answer the question, but it does offer a potential alternative. Additionally this option may be a good 'catch all' in some instances especially ones where regex just cant accomodate all permutations of width.

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna use some RegEx:

```
//use SimpleXMLElement to parse the attributes
$img = new SimpleXMLElement($imgStr);
$pattern = '~([a-z-]+)\s*:\s*([^;$]+)~si';

//convert the value of the style attribute into an associative array
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $img['style'], $match)) {
    $style[] = array_combine(
        array_map('strtolower', $match[1]),
        array_map(function($val) { return trim($val, '"\' '); }, $match[2])
    );  
}

// add the width and height attributes and get the new html
$img->addAttribute('width', $style[0]['width']);
$img->addAttribute('height', $style[0]['height']);
$newImgStr = $img->asXML();

// remove the width and height rules from the style attribute
$newImgStr = preg_replace('/width:([^;$]+);/', '', $newImgStr);
$newImgStr = preg_replace('/height:([^;$]+);/', '', $newImgStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the style is already loaded with the img then the solutiona can be made with JQUERY :

```
$(function () {

                  width=$(this).css("width");
                  height=$(this).css("height");
                  $(this).attr("width",width);
                  $(this).attr("height",height);
 });
```

Hope it will serve your purposes.

Comment: the question specifically asked about a solution in php